# Storing Ciphertext in Firebase - Key Choice and Storage

Tags: encryption

I am building an application where I want that data submitted by the user is stored encrypted in the database, such that only the user can access it.

I started reading into cryptography and it looks like I need to convert the data to ciphertext, e.g. using AES, Rabbit, Blowfish or ChaCha20, which are well supported in my environment. These functions take the data and a key as input, sometimes also an iv.

I already know that the iv can be stored next to the ciphertext, it should be random and unique, but doesn't need to be a secret.
Now regarding the key (or passphrase), I have the following questions:

Assuming I choose a single key application wide, it definitely needs to be kept a secret. Is it sufficient to use a single key, assuming it is kept secret?

But choosing a single key for all data means that in theory if it does get leaked, everything can be encrypted, correct? And the 'only the user can decrypt its own data' part isn't fully true anymore either right?

Would it be wiser to choose a key for every user, for example something that is derived from a unique user id, or the e-mail?

Comment: yes on the last bit: a KDF, like [PBKDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2), or [scrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt), but the input need be non-public